# Dual 4K monitors with 2017 Macbook Pro base model

Tags: macbook-pro, display, 4k

I have the base model 13 inch 2017 Macbook Pro and want to use dual 4K monitors. I know Apple officially supports the use of two 4K monitors, but I am unsure if the performance will be poor.

From what I understand, the graphics resources are shared with the CPU so will running the 4K monitors negatively impact upon CPU performance?

My workload mostly involves web browsing, viewing 4K videos and programming. Will there be issues with lag or stuttering? Has anyone tried running two 4K monitors at 60Hz with the integrated graphics?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Questions such as this is inherently opinionated and is likely to be closed.  Normally, I would try to edit so it won't be opinionated.  However, it's too broad for me to narrow down.  Performance means something different for each user.  Consider quantifying this descriptor so it becomes something that can objectively addressed.

Comment: @Allan All good, I have updated my question so hopefully is more clear.

Comment: "Lag or stuttering" doing *what*?  Looking at spreadsheets?  Watching movies?  Playing games?  At what resolutions?  What frame rate?  This is like saying "I know my truck can pull a trailer but will there be issues with the load?"

Comment: @Allan I don't think this is opinion based, since (although broad) lag and stuttering are concrete and quantifiable. However, I do agree that it's too broad, since the workload hasn't been discussed yet.

Comment: @JMY1000 - the "opinionated" close was prior to the edit which then made it less opinionated but too broad.  There's no facility to reclassify a vote.

Comment: @Allan Added more details about the workload, but doesn't seem like many people have experience with this.